# Resources for developing a C++ MySQL application for Linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I'm going to be developing a C++ application that uses a MySQL database.

I've written similar apps in Java using JDBC, as well as the Spring Framework.

Are there equivalent libraries for C++?  What have you had the most success with?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the MySQL C API, it is the simplest solution. You can easily write a class to wrap up the C api for your own uses.

Answer (score 1):

I have enjoyed working with [SQLAPI++](http://www.sqlapi.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I found [QtSql](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtsql.html) to be easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like writing a data access layer using the [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html) is going to be the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Connector/C++ is a C++ implementation of JDBC 4.0

The reference customers who use MySQL Connector/C++ are:
 - OpenOffice
 - MySQL Workbench

[Learn more](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,221298)

Comment: would definitely recommend AGAINST anything directly from MySQL (Oracle) themselves... the API does not work on various MacOS and Windows versions, libraries/bins/sources are not up to date in many cases etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

[QTL](https://github.com/znone/qtl) is a modern C++ header only library that abstracts much of the boilerplate of the plain C MySQL library. It is actually very pleasant to use. It requires a compiler that supports C++ 11.

This library also works from Ubuntu while connecting to Aurora DB, something MySQL Connector/C++ stopped doing since Ubuntu 20.04.

Link here:  https://github.com/znone/qtl