# What is a good MySQL library for C or C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for developing a C++ MySQL application for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319297/resources-for-developing-a-c-mysql-application-for-linux)

Does anyone know of a MySQL **library** for C/C++ **with tutorials** that is easy to use?

Im using a Mac and Xcode.

Comment: It seems this is quite a common question.   Try here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319297/resources-for-developing-a-c-mysql-application-for-linux

Answer (score 8):

[MySQL Connector for C++](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) from the MySQL website. Here is a [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html) directly on the MySQL site again. [This](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/) might be worth taking a look too.

DISCLAIMER : I don't know anything about C++ MySQL programming on a Mac. I found those links through quick Google searches and lightning-fast reading of the articles.